# How to configure ubuntu ldap client to get password policies from server?

Tags: 12.04, authentication, ldap

I have a ldap server on CentOS, 389-ds. I configured the client, ubuntu 12.04, to authenticate on that base and it works very well. But it don't gets the password policies from server. For example, if i set the policy to force user to change the password on first login, ubuntu ignores it and logs him in, always.

How can i setup the client to get the policies?

Here are the client files:

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd: files ldap 
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup: nis
sudoers: ldap files
```

---

common-auth

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_cap.so
```

---

common-account

```
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so 
account requisite           pam_deny.so
account required

        pam_permit.so
```

---

common-password

```
password    requisite           pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password    [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die] pam_ldap.so use_authtok try_first_pass
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
password    required            pam_permit.so
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

---

common-session

```
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
session requisite           pam_deny.so
session required            pam_permit.so
session optional            pam_umask.so
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional            pam_ldap.so 
session optional            pam_ck_connector.so nox11
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
```

---

/etc/ldap.conf

```
base dc=a,dc=b,dc=c
uri ldaps://a.b.c/
ldap_version 3
rootbinddn cn=directory manager
pam_password md5
sudoers_base ou=SUDOers,dc=a,dc=b,dc=c
pam_lookup_policy yes
pam_check_host_attr yes
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers avahi,avahi-autoipd,backup,bin,colord,daemon,games,gnats,hplip,irc,kernoops,libuuid,lightdm,list,lp,mail,man,messagebus,news,proxy,pulse,root,rtkit,saned,speech-dispatcher,sshd,sync,sys,syslog,usbmux,uucp,whoopsie,www-data
```

---

/etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
BASE    dc=a,dc=b,dc=c
URI ldaps://a.b.c/
ssl on
use_sasl no
tls_checkpeer no
sudoers_base ou=SUDOers,dc=a,dc=b,dc=c
sudoers_debug 2
pam_lookup_policy yes
pam_check_host_attr yes
pam_lookup_policy yes
pam_check_host_attr yes
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
TLS_REQCERT never
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed all the libldap related libraries - for eg., libnss-ldap, libpam-ldap, libkrb53. Post that try imposing the policies once again.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do requires setuid binaries you probably are encountering this:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=658896

http://www.bebt.de/blog/debian/archives/2011/02/20/T13_14_34/index.html